# Getting user's time zone with javascript and converting date and time in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I need to convert PHP timestamps according to the user's computer timezone.

`Server's timezone is: UTC +1`

**To do this, first I use javascript.**

```
<script>
var time_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
time_offset = Number(time_offset) * 60 + 3600;  //here I convert minutes to seconds and add 3600 seconds (1 hour) which is the difference between server's time and UTC.
var d = document.write(time_offset);
</script>
```

**PHP**

And here I got lost. Don't know how to use `strtotime` because `time_offset` can be negative and positive number:

```
$date_convert = '2022-10-27 12:25:46';
$offset = ob_get_clean();

// echo $offset; outputs negative value -3600 

$newdate = date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime("$date_convert + $offset seconds"));

echo $newdate;
```

This produces:

`01/01/1970 01:00`

Comment: `"$date_convert + $offset seconds"` is literally the string `"$date_convert + $offset seconds"` - `strtotime` doesn't know what date `"$date_convert + $offset seconds"` is

Comment: @JaromandaX it's PHP code, inside a double-quoted string it will substitute the values of `$date_convert` and `$offset`

Comment: @SamMiguel check your `$offset` value. See https://3v4l.org/XLcnq - only when it is a number, it works as expected. In all other cases you get the start off time (PHP time it is). So you probably do not have the right value in your variable.

Comment: You can't pass values from JS to PHP by using `document.write`. You need to transfer them via some of form of request, typically a form submission or an ajax request

Comment: @Nick if I can not pass, how ´echo $offset´ outputs ´-3600´?

Comment: @SanMiguel you must have more code than you are showing us... or are you sure that's the `echo` and not the `document.write`? Does `-3600` still show up if you delete the `document.write`?